# Install a specific version of node and npm using brew (or not using brew)

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew, nvm

I'm trying to set my environment to node `v14.18.2` and NPM `7.24.2`.

When I `brew install node` I get npm `8.5.2` and node `v17.7.2`.

If I change to node@14 formula:

`brew unlink node`

`brew link --overwrite node@14`

This gives me node `v14.19.1` and npm `6.14.16`.

How can I get the exact versions of npm and node I want using brew?

Alternatively, is brew not the way to go for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I used nvm instead. First install nvm `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`.

Switch to a new terminal.

`nvm install 14.18.2`

`nvm use 14.18.2`

`npm install -g npm@7.24.2`